# Perl replace string

Tags: perl, if-statement, replace

Is it possible to replace in Perl with an `if`?

I want to replace if 'true' from a database with `erledigt;`

```
while ( my ($username, $description, $checked, $record_date) = $query4->fetchrow_array ) {

    if ( $checked == 'true' ) {
        print $fh4 'erledigt'
    }
    else {
        print $fh4 ($checked)
    }

    {
        print $fh4 "$username;$description;$checked;$record_date\n";
    }
}
```

I get `erledigt` in every line except for `true`.

Comment: I think you meant `($checked eq 'true')` - `==` is for comparing numbers

Comment: `print $fh4` does not write into the database, it writes into a file instead. Is that what you really want to do? I see you are using DBI because of the `fetchrow_array` method, so there's also the [`do` method](http://p3rl.org/DBI#do) together with an SQL `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement. If you please would amend your question with the database schema/column names, someone can write an answer with the exactly correct SQL.

Comment: @ChrisTurner okay yes thanks .. but it also doesent replace 'true'

Comment: @daxim sorry yes it writes into a file and the database is not necessary in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (my ($username, $description, $checked, $record_date) = $query4->fetchrow_array) {
    # change the "checked" text when it's "true",
    # otherwise leave it as it is.
    $checked = 'erledigt' if $checked eq 'true';
    print $fh4 "$username;$description;$checked;$record_date\n"; 
}
```